CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleDataTransport"
I am trying to update the pods of my project using this command : cd ios && pod update && Pod install && cd - but I receive this error :
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleDataTransport":
  In Podfile:
    firebase_messaging (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_messaging/ios`) was resolved to 15.1.0, which depends on
      Firebase/Messaging (= 11.0.0) was resolved to 11.0.0, which depends on
        FirebaseMessaging (~> 11.0.0) was resolved to 11.0.0, which depends on
          GoogleDataTransport (~> 10.0)

    mobile_scanner (from `.symlinks/plugins/mobile_scanner/ios`) was resolved to 5.2.2, which depends on
      GoogleMLKit/BarcodeScanning (~> 6.0.0) was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
        MLKitBarcodeScanning (~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
          MLKitCommon (~> 11.0) was resolved to 11.0.0, which depends on
            GoogleDataTransport (< 10.0, >= 9.4.1)

I tried to clean my project flutter clean
Deleted my pubspec.lock
Deleted my podfile.lock
Updated my cocoapods
gem install cocoapods
pod repo update

And get again my packages with flutter pub get
But nothing works, I tried to do the same on an previous version of my project but it doesn't work anymore neither.
Here my package versions :
  firebase_core: ^3.4.0
  firebase_core_web: ^2.17.5
  firebase_messaging: ^15.1.0
  firebase_messaging_web: ^3.8.13
  mobile_scanner: ^5.2.2

My flutter version:
Flutter 3.24.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 80c2e84975 (5 weeks ago) • 2024-07-30 23:06:49 +0700
Engine • revision b8800d88be
Tools • Dart 3.5.0 • DevTools 2.37.2


Do not use "CocoaPods" or "Carthage".  Ancient history.  Ordinary SPM is now the only way to go.

Following what this post said : github-issue google_ml_kit_flutter
I changed my firebase versions to a 4 month older versions :
  firebase_core: ^2.31.0
  firebase_core_web: ^2.17.0
  firebase_messaging: ^14.9.2
  firebase_messaging_web: ^3.8.5

Next I typed the following command to get my packages and install my pods :
flutter clean && flutter pub get && cd ios && pod update && Pod install && cd -
My pods are installed correctly.

You can be more up to date than this, using mobile scanner v5 I have the following:
firebase_core: ^3.3.0
firebase_messaging: ^15.0.4
firebase_remote_config: ^5.0.4

There is not yet a GoogleMLKit version compatible with Firebase 11.x. In the meantime, continue to use Firebase 10.x.

Thank you for your response, do you know if there is a promised deadline for the upgrade of the GoogleMLKit version compatible with Firebase 11.x ? To know when we will be able to upgrade again our firebase packages.
