CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod GTMSessionFetcher/Core
I recently updated my Flutter version from 3.7 to 3.16, along with some libraries. Now, I’m encountering an issue when running pod install in the ios folder, and the following error is thrown:
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GTMSessionFetcher/Core":
  In Podfile:
    google_sign_in_ios (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_sign_in_ios/darwin`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      GoogleSignIn (~> 7.1.0) was resolved to 7.1.0, which depends on
        GTMAppAuth (< 5.0, >= 4.1.1) was resolved to 4.1.1, which depends on
          GTMSessionFetcher/Core (< 4.0, >= 3.3)

    google_sign_in_ios (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_sign_in_ios/darwin`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      GoogleSignIn (~> 7.1.0) was resolved to 7.1.0, which depends on
        GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 3.3)

    mobile_scanner (from `.symlinks/plugins/mobile_scanner/ios`) was resolved to 3.5.6, which depends on
      GoogleMLKit/BarcodeScanning (~> 4.0.0) was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends on
        MLKitBarcodeScanning (~> 3.0.0) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
          MLKitCommon (~> 9.0) was resolved to 9.0.0, which depends on
            GTMSessionFetcher/Core (< 3.0, >= 1.1)

Here is my Podfile:
platform :ios, '14.0'

ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  pod 'GTMSessionFetcher', :modular_headers => true

  pod 'GoogleUtilities'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',
        'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',
        'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=1'
      ]
    end
  end
end

target 'ImageNotification' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'GoogleUtilities'
end


Here are the package versions mentioned in the error from pubspec.yaml:

google_sign_in: ^6.2.1
mobile_scanner: ^3.5.7

Steps I’ve tried:
Running flutter pub get before pod install.
Cleaning the CocoaPods cache:
cd ios
rm Podfile.lock
pod cache clean --all
sudo arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update
pod repo update
pod install

i also tried updating mobile_scanner to 4.0.1
Despite trying all the above, I still get the version conflict.

It's the same issue (logic) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78958362/cocoapods-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-pod-googledatatransport

In other words, your external libs depends on other libs, and each version depends on different version of each one. But you can have only one version for each external lib (be it directly set by you, or because it's needed for another one). You need to find a common ground.

By comparing all the GTMSessionFetcher/Core (< 3.0, >= 1.1) GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 3.3) and GTMSessionFetcher/Core (< 4.0, >= 3.3), check the different "parent lib" that can use the same version of GTMSessionFetcher/Core.
